# VF Page "Selectors should be known"

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, css, html

I am new on VF page. So I have created a simple css method in my vf page like:

```html
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        tdstyleform {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

And using it like:

```html
<td class="tdstyleform">
    <b>COMPLAINT FORM</b>
</td>
```

This gives a Code quality error stating "Selectors should be known". If I don't create the css method and use it directly inside the td class, i still get a code quality issue. Can anyone please help what can be done here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the "." before the class name in the CSS code. The "." is used to specify that you're defining a class in CSS.

```html
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .tdstyleform {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<td class="tdstyleform">
    <b>COMPLAINT FORM</b>
</td>
```

With this change, the CSS code should be correctly associated with the class `tdstyleform`.

Comment: Let me quickly try that!

Comment: did it worked ?

Comment: Yes it did. Thanks! :)